# how to tell which application is asking for permissions when prompted

Tags: permissions, security, authentication

In ubuntu 20 I get prompted to enter my password for some mystery application frequently. I write services across root and userspace and need at least a PID or name to have even a notion whether the application should get permissions to keyrings. Why ask in the first place?

Comment: On a desktop it is likely only 1 that does this: networkmanager, It wants permission to access internet and it will ask it at every time you login if the keyring holds a password for it.

Comment: It asks in the first place if your keyring password doesn't match your login password anymore. Make the two similar again, and it will stop pestering you.